# Passing different type than parameter type

Tags: java, types

If I would have a variable `a` declared by `A a` and a method `m` with `void m(B b)`. Is there any way that calling `m(a)` would work? Or can this never work because `a` is of type `A` and `b` of type `B`.

Comment: if `B` and `A` are in any sense related to another (parent - child) then it can work

Comment: Example: `B` is `List`, `A` is `ArrayList`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't understand how these are then related. Because if B is a list and A an arraylist, then they are still different types right?

Comment: `List` is an interface that `ArrayList` implements. A method with a parameter of type `List` accepts all Lists that implement this interface, e.g `LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, `MyPersonalListIJustImplementedLastWeek`, etc..

Answer (score 4):

If `A` extends `B`, it can be passed as argument to that function. If not and `A` contains values suitable for `B` you have to create an instance of `B` and fill it with the required values of the instance of `A`.

Comment: Similarly, it will work if `A` implements `B`. It was never stated that `B` is necessarily a class.

Answer (score 3):

This works if `A` is a subclass of `B`

Answer (score 2):

This could work in two scenarios:

- When `A` is a `B`, i.e. inheritance or interface implementation, or
- When `A` and `B` are primitive data types, and an implicit conversion exists from `A` to `B.

Here is an example:

```
void m(long b) {
    ...
}
int a = 123;
m(a); // This compiles and runs correctly
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible when `A` is a subclass of `B` or we can say `A` extends `B`, 
this is known as **inheritance** in programming language, in this `A` will be a child of the class `B` and inherit all its properties

**you can check it from the link below**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm